# free secure distributed make system for linux

Tags: makefile, distributed, data-processing

Are there any good language-agnostic distributed make systems for linux that are secure and free?

**Background Information:**

I run scientific experiments (computer-science ones) that sometimes have large dependency trees, occasionally on the order of thousands or tens of thousands of tree nodes.  This dependency tree is over the data files, data processing executables, and results files.

I've experimented with various techniques over the years including:

1. Rolling my own dependency tracker using a database and running a script on each worker machine.  This can get a bit cumbersome, especially when trying to work with non-scripting languages.
2. Putting all the processing commands in single makefile, with pseudo-targets that can be manually "built" on different worker machines.  This requires no special tools, but it can be a pain to manually break up the work into evenly-sized pseudo-target chunks and correctly invoking "make" on each worker box.
3. *[distmake](http://distmake.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/pmwiki.php)*: automatically distribute the execution of commands from a single makefile...

I'm basically looking for something like distmake, but more secure.  As far as I can tell, distmake essentially leaves a wide-open backdoor into each worker node.

It would also be nice if a replacement were more robust than distmake.  If you break out of the main distmake call, it can shut down the backdoor servers, but it doesn't properly kill the executing processes on the worker nodes.

---

**Clarifications:**

I am processing data with the makefile, not compiling and linking with gcc.  From what I read in the documentation, distcc is a specialized tool for distributing gcc.  I'll be running my own executables on very large data files hosted on a shared filesystem, not gcc on source files, so distcc isn't helpful.

The worker nodes are externally-visible machines, so I want any worker daemons to be at least as secure as ssh.  As best I can tell without reading the source, distmake worker daemons open up a port and will accept commands from anyone who attaches to it.  They will execute the commands as the user who started the daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also [distcc](http://distcc.org), which claims to be able to operate over SSH (though unless distmake is somehow very strange, you should be able to restrict access to localhost and build SSH tunnels to run the build), and [icecream](http://en.opensuse.org/Icecream).

*Update:* Because the goal isn't a distributed compile, but a distributed computation that just happens to be using `make` as a bootstrap, it makes more sense to use a tool that is designed for distributed computation like [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/ProjectMain). The comments below indicate [condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/) as the chosen platform.

Comment: I'll look into the ssh tunnels.  It looks like distcc and icecream are for compilation and linking only.  icecream's homepage warns that it should not be used in insecure environments.

Comment: In that case, why aren't you just writing a BOINC engine?

Comment: Ah, grid computing...why didn't I think of that.  I think condor may do what I want.  Would you mind adding grid computing solutions to your response (or creating a new response) for the sake of future readerrs?

Answer (score 3):

Dependencies are hard to manage, and I don't know of any perfect system that does what you want without a significant amount of work.

The closest thing that I've used is the following setup:
- a Condor queue to manage the machines in your cluster
- the Condor DAGMAN meta-scheduler to submit jobs that are interdependent. DAGMAN is an acronym for Directed Acyclic Graph MANager, in which a directed acyclic graph is used to represent the dependencies between your jobs.

We've done this for an iterative scientific protocol in our lab very successfully and it's worked great, although it was a learning experience for a very talented postdoc to get the initial implementation running. It does require that you set up and run a Condor cluster which is non-trivial, but I assume you have either Condor or something similar to manage all of your machines. It might be that Sun GridEngine has something analogous that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Although it probably will be complicated to integrate transparently with 'make', GNU parallel seems to provide a convenient option to distribute commands across servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're diligent with dependencies (i.e. make -jxx works fine locally), distcc is probably what you want. Its very easy to utilize and works happily with several popular CC caches. Again, proper dependencies being the key, especially when using a cache to help speed up the process of re-building.

If your using GCC to generate dependencies beyond the scope of module dependencies in the makefile itself, you'll probably love distcc. I've been using it on a small build farm with great success .. but my setup/tree is nowhere near as elaborate as the one you describe.

Comment: I'm processing data files, not source files, so I don't think distcc can help.  I do have proper dependencies though (make -jxx does work great locally for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [AT&T `nmake`](http://www.research.att.com/~gsf/) combined with the `coshell` program.  I don't know how to evaluate security, but Glenn Fowler's group is full of great engineers who have done a lot of seriously good stuff.  I would trust them with my source code :-)  Their best known tool might be [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  coshell is "as secure as rsh", which means that like distmake it's probably quite easy to spoof.  Otherwise it seems like a better tool than distmake.

Comment: `coshell` claims to be able to use `ssh` as well as `rsh`.  I consider `rsh` wildly insecure.  I don't know what you think of `ssh`.

Comment: I do consider ssh to be secure, but... coshell seems to use ssh only to spawn the coshell daemon.  The daemon seems to open up its own port and communicate through that, and not through ssh.  Thus it securely opens an insecure port, meaning it's insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Makeflow also seems like an excellent solution: http://www.cse.nd.edu/~ccl/software/makeflow/